# Convert Date into ISO Date Format C#

Tags: c#

I have a Date value for example:

```
string date = "02/14/2015" //(MM/DD/YYY)
```

I want to convert it into ISO Date Format. Is there anyway to do this..

Comment: this may help:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114983/given-a-datetime-object-how-do-i-get-a-iso-8601-date-in-string-format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
string date = "02/14/2015"

DateTime NewDate= DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "MM/DD/YYYY", 
CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

string NewFmt=NewDate.ToString("yyyy/MM/DD");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format, provider);` function.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

**Example:**

```
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
string date = "02/14/2015";
string format = "dd/mm/yyyy";

// Result is now a DateTime and can be easily converted
DateTime result = DateTime.ParseExact(date, format, provider);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This...

```
string date = "02/14/2015";
DateTime d2 = DateTime.Parse(date, null, DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind);
```