# Rendering in IE with fullcalendar

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, fullcalendar

I am using the fullcalendar,

but in IE 10 or 11 the events are not render correct,

I have this:

```
public static List<DiaryEvent> LoadAllAppointmentsInDateRange(double start, double end)
        {
            var fromDate = ConvertFromUnixTimestamp(start);
            var toDate = ConvertFromUnixTimestamp(end);
            using (LolaBikeContext ent = new LolaBikeContext())
            {
                var rslt = ent.AppointmentDiarys.Where(s => s.DateTimeScheduled >= fromDate && System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.AddMinutes(s.DateTimeScheduled, s.AppointmentLength) <= toDate);

                List<DiaryEvent> result = new List<DiaryEvent>();
                foreach (var item in rslt)
                {
                    DiaryEvent rec = new DiaryEvent();
                    rec.ID = item.Id;
                    rec.SomeImportantKeyID = item.SomeImportantKey;
                    rec.StartDateString = item.DateTimeScheduled.ToString("MMMM/dd/yyyy"); // "s" is a preset format that outputs as: "2009-02-27T12:12:22"
                    rec.StarEvent = item.DateTimeScheduled.ToString("HH:mm"); // ParseExact(start, "HH:mm", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).ToString();      //item.DateTimeScheduled.ToString("MMMM/dd/yyyy");
                    rec.EndDateString = item.DateTimeScheduled.AddMinutes(item.AppointmentLength).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH\\:mm\\:ss.fffffffzzz");//  "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ"); // field AppointmentLength is in minutes
                    rec.Title = item.Title;// +" - " + item.AppointmentLength.ToString() + " mins";

                    rec.AppointmentLength = item.AppointmentLength.ToString();

                    rec.StatusString = Enums.GetName<AppointmentStatus>((AppointmentStatus)item.StatusENUM);
                    rec.StatusColor = Enums.GetEnumDescription<AppointmentStatus>(rec.StatusString);
                    string ColorCode = rec.StatusColor.Substring(0, rec.StatusColor.IndexOf(":"));
                    rec.ClassName = rec.StatusColor.Substring(rec.StatusColor.IndexOf(":") + 1, rec.StatusColor.Length - ColorCode.Length - 1);
                    rec.StatusColor = ColorCode;
                    result.Add(rec);
                }

                return result;
            }

        }
```

and especially this line:

```
  rec.EndDateString = item.DateTimeScheduled.AddMinutes(item.AppointmentLength).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH\\:mm\\:ss.fffffffzzz");// is not rendering correct.
```

I have read that it has to be in: ISO 8601, so I have looked at this thread:

[Given a DateTime object, how do I get an ISO 8601 date in string format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114983/given-a-datetime-object-how-do-i-get-a-iso-8601-date-in-string-format)

but that doesnt work. IE is rendering the events not correct

Thank you!!

see the different pictures[image]
The correct image:
[image]

Comment: Somebody??? will be nice!!

Comment: Somebody home??? realy strange

Answer (score 0):

I think youare missing the "s" format specifier, which  is described as Sortable date/time pattern; conforms to ISO 8601

The EventStart comes in ISO 8601 format and you will need to convert it. you can follow this example to convert current to ISO 8601:

```
DateTime.UtcNow.ToString ( "s", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture )
```

Here's a post about that : [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/115034/1837329) 
As for your code try this instead for your `startdatestring` and `enddatestring`:

```
 rec.StartDateString = item.DateTimeScheduled.ToString("s");


rec.EndDateString = item.DateTimeScheduled.AddMinutes(item.AppointmentLength).ToString("s");
```

Comment: I have tried your answare, but then in IE it looks like the image Iv sent here. it fills all the day