# What's the best way to post data to Elastic Search using powershell?

Tags: powershell, elasticsearch

Should I use convert-tojson or roll my own. Should I use invoke-restrequest, invokeweb-request, System.net.WebClient or system.net.http.HttpClient?

Sometimes I seem to post successfully, although the data isn't indexed.

```
{"_index":"dropstorage","_type":"connectionstats","_id":"97e156a5-4d16-48d4-84e8-fcc723aea1ae",
"_version":1,"found":true,"_source":{
"hnas":  1,
"active":  70,
"id":  "97e156a5-4d16-48d4-84e8-fcc723aea1ae",
"total":  "70",
"date":  "4/9/2015 9:03:36 AM"
}}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend the following approach:

```
$body = ConvertTo-Json $curatorResult -Compress
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $uri -ContentType 'application/json'-Body $body -ErrorAction Stop | Out-Null
```

Comment: Also fun fact. convertto-json doesn't do a convert get-date in a way that elastic search likes.

Comment: Apprarently you want it in iso 8601 cause that's what newtonsoft does.
[netwonsoft](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DatesInJSON.htm) and [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114983/given-a-datetime-object-how-do-i-get-a-iso-8601-date-in-string-format)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a walkthrough for using Elasticsearch from first-principles using PowerShell. There are notes on when to use GET and POST, how to do serialization, mass data generation, and how to interact with many calls directly.

Near the start, you'll find a discussion of making PowerShell calls compatible with Elasticsearch (yes, there's a trick).

[Learning Elasticsearch with PowerShell](https://netfxharmonics.com/2015/11/learningelasticps)

Answer (score 0):

Check out [`Elastic.Console`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Elastic.Console), a small PowerShell module for working with Elasticsearch using PowerShell and PowerShell Core. It offers autocompletion on API endpoint paths and methods for a chosen Elasticsearch version.

After installing with

```bsh
Install-Module -Name Elastic.Console -AllowPrerelease
```

You can send data with

```bsh
$body = ConvertTo-Json $curatorResult -Compress
$response = es -Method POST "/{index}/_doc/{id}" -Body $body
```

The request body can be a JSON string literal, a Hashtable, or a path to a file containing JSON.

Run the following to see full docs and examples

```bsh
Get-Help es -Full
```