# Why the month in Angular date filter is capitalised?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datefilter

I'm afraid if this question doesn't fit in this context.I wanted to know why the month
(MM) of date filter in Angular in-built date filter is capitalised while the date(dd) and year(yyyy) are written in small letters.It dosen't work if I apply `mm` to the filter.

Sample Code:  `<span>{{1288323623006 | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z'}}</span><br>`

Ref: [Angular Date Filters](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)

Comment: But what is the use of minutes for date filtering?

Comment: your sample code format with minutes

Comment: @MANOJ It's a bit of a misnomer. `Date` is actually a `Date/Time`. The capitalization of `MM` is standard string.format in a lot of languages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its is used to differentiate between months(MM) and minutes(mm).

Also as RGraham, has said, you will find that in most of the languages it is treated like that and more or less it has become a standard.

Answer (score 0):

It is to distinguish between month and minutes. It is actually a DateTime.

In your example, you can see that both capital MM and small mm exists:

> yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss

This way, you can *even* format it to show only minutes.

I modified the official example on [AngularJS docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) to get these results:

```
{{1288323623006 | date:'medium'}}: Oct 29, 2010 6:40:23 AM
{{1288323623006 | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z'}}: 2010-10-29 06:40:23 +0300
{{1288323623006 | date:"MM/dd/yyyy 'at' h:mma"}}: 10/29/2010 at 6:40AM
{{1288323623006 | date:"MM mm GGGG}}: 10 40 Anno Domini
```

It [is used in another languages too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114983/given-a-datetime-object-how-do-i-get-a-iso-8601-date-in-string-format/115002#115002) when you need to apply cultural / standard formatting.