# Formatting DateTime to String in C#

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, c#-5.0

How I can format a `DateTime` in C# like this `2015-09-24T09:30:00+05:30`?

I found a method like this `date.ToString("o");`, but which is formatting the string like this `2015-10-05T09:30:00.0000000+05:30`. Adding the additional `.0000000` to the string.

Any one please help to get this corrected.

Comment: See [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @juharr I suspect that the format sought is available using a [Standard Date and Time Format String](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx) but that `"o"` is just not the right one.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114983/given-a-datetime-object-how-do-i-get-a-iso-8601-date-in-string-format

Comment: What's with all the downvotes??

Comment: @PoweredByOrange I did not vote, but I suspect very strongly that the downvotes reflect the apparent lack of any effort on the part of the OP to locate the `ToString` documentation or to do any other research to solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

There aren't any shorthand options but this should do the trick.

```
date.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz")
```

Refer to Microsoft's documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Note that the `':'` character represents the culture-specific time separator, so the format string given will produce an incorrect result in certain cultures.  You can escape the character to force a literal `:`.