# Standardising DateTime.Now and DateTime.Utc

Tags: c#, datetime

I am working on an application that receives alerts from a server. While processing the alerts, I calculate the last time the an alert was sent by doing the following:

```
TimeSpan? alertDiffTimespan = DateTime.UtcNow - serverEventInfo.lastAlert
```

An accurate timespan is important because it allows me to figure out whether a server is active or not.

As of late, I noticed that sometimes `serverEventInfo.lastAlert` is correct (i.e. being formatted as DateTime.UtcNow) and other times it is an hour ahead/behind the current time (i.e. DateTime.Now). I have tried the following:

```
TimeSpan? alertDiffTimeSpan = DateTime.UtcNow - serverEventInfo.lastAlert.Value.ToUniversalTime()
```

but then it means that all the values coming in that are set as `DateTime.UtcNow` are formatted incorrectly but the ones set as `DateTime.Now` are correct.

I have tried determining the DateTime.Kind as well, however it keeps flagging as Unspecified each time, so no distinction.

Is there anything I can do to standardise the incoming DateTime values within my application so that no matter whether a `UtcNow` or a `Now` value comes in, I can still process it correctly and get a correct `alertDiffTimeSpan`?

The dates are in format `{0:MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt}` and set as follows `String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt}", DateTime.Now)` or  `String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt}", DateTime.UtcNow)` on the server.

Comment: What format are you receiving the datetimes in? If they don't specify whether they're UTC or not.. there's no way you can guess it by yourself.

Comment: https://xkcd.com/1179/ is the only acceptable answer... (But it is very hard to see where your problems are coming from as post somewhat lack information)

Comment: `DateTime.Now` != `DateTime.Utc(Now)`. The former is adjusted to local time (based from machine's regional settings), where the latter uses ISO 8601 format. The safest way to deal user inputs with different timezone is converting to ISO format first, then display it as local one.

Comment: If it's only one server and you know exactly which time zone it runs, you *might* get away with two checks. Once treating it as UTC and once treating it as local server time. But that's pretty bad. If you have any control over the server at all, figure out, why it's sending UTC/local seemingly willynilly and make sure that it *always* sends UTC.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - I don't think the submitted format is the problem. The problem seems to be that the submitted `DateTime` switches between being UTC and (server) local time with no indication what it is exactly.

Comment: @Rob they are set in the standard DateTime format, unfortunately the issue I have is that o can't figure out whether they are coming in as Utc or Now.

Comment: @methuselah What do you mean by the standard DateTime format? There are many 'standard' formats. Does it include an offset?

Comment: @Corak there are multiple servers all sending out alerts, the format is okay but sometimes I have noticed they come in as Local or Utc which makes it difficult to process

Comment: @Rob a standard date time string

Comment: @methuselah - then again: best way would be to make sure every server sends UTC. Or at least make the servers send their UTC-offset, too. Worst (imho): keep a list of servers that don't send UTC and have their offset...

Comment: @methuselah I think you're missing what I'm asking. Can you *show* us this string and format? Saying it's a standard string means nothing. There are many standard formats. Some include offsets, some do not.

Comment: @methuselah - "the great thing about standards is: there are so many to choose from". So for example is it: `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"`?

Comment: @Corak I don't have this information on me at the moment. But I now understand exactly what you are talking about. When I get it, I will add it to the question.

Comment: If the servers are sending local times without time zone information, you basically don't have enough information. You need to fix that at the source.

Comment: @Corak please see update to question

Comment: @methuselah - Okay, so if you can change it on the server, you should again only ever use `UtcNow`, never just `Now` (at least when communicating with the "outside"). If you can at least change the format string, put some `z`s in there, that way you'll at least get the time zone offset (see [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) for more information). Either way, you *need* to change something on those servers.

Comment: Also note that `"MM/dd/yyyy"` is culture dependent! `"/"` as the date separator could be different in different cultures. For example in `de-DE` you'd get `05.17.2017` from that. So I'd strongly advise, you use `"yyyy-MM-dd"`, which is the ISO standard for dates. (which was also the point of Alexei) -- Also, if you use `"HH"` instead of `"hh"`, you can remove the `"tt"`.

Comment: @Corak based on comments OP tries to guess correct value instead of relying on full ISO8601 format with timezone... So proper recommendation about format should be "o" (or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114983/given-a-datetime-object-how-do-i-get-an-iso-8601-date-in-string-format)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - ah, you are of course correct about using `"o"`. I only ever use custom formats (when needed) to be in full control so I tend to forget these useful standard formats.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't guess correct value of DateTime if you don't have time zone information specified in some way. It sounds like you servers may "randomly" pick between local (possibly multiple time zones) and UTC and you have no way to know which one is which.

Fixes:

- align *all* servers to return UTC time and continue using formats that don't specify timezone. When reading server value specify Utc at the end: `DateTime.SpecifyKind(parsedDateTime, DateTimeKind.Utc)`
- require time zone information in serialized data. Preferably use full ISO8601 like "2017-05-17T08:27:27.0314698Z" (`dateTime.ToString("o")`, more info - [Given a DateTime object, how do I get an ISO 8601 date in string format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114983/given-a-datetime-object-how-do-i-get-an-iso-8601-date-in-string-format), or if you like pictures more - https://xkcd.com/1179/)

Do not use any formats that are culture-specific (like default `ToString()`) in serialized data unless you have 100% confidence that all servers configured with identical locale settings and your parsing code always specifies the same culture when reading values. Again ISO8601 is safer choice.