# .net Core 2.0 Protect Datetime

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am using IDataProtector to encrypt my data before storing into the database. All strings work fine for example:

```
LastName = _protector.Protect(student.LastName)
```

However I can't use Protect with:

```
 public DateTime EnrollmentDate { get; set; }
```

Using:

```
 Student nstudent = new Student
        {
            LastName = _protector.Protect(student.LastName),
            EnrollmentDate = _protector.Protect(student.EnrollmentDate)
        };
```

I get this error:

```
cannot convert from 'System.DateTime' to 'byte[]'
```

Comment: DataProtector is simple, it knows how to encrypt a byte[].  As a *convenience* there is an extension method that handles a string.  But that's where it ends.  It is up to you to convert a DateTime to byte[] if you want to take advantage of it.  Like BitConverter.GetBytes(dt.ToBinary()) for example.  Or to consider that there is no point in encrypting dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot protect / unprotect to and from a fixed-length data type like `DateTime`. The extension method for strings creates a `byte[]` representation, encrypts it and then creates a base64 string representation of the protected value. This works because the protected and unprotected strings can be of different length. But `DateTime` is a struct with a fixed length, even if you use the backing `long` tick count, it only gives you 4 bytes. This requires you to use a different representation to store the protected value.

So you could have

```
byte[] protectedDateTime = protector.Protect(BitConverter.GetBytes(student.EnrollmentDate.Ticks));
DateTime unprotectedDateTime = new DateTime(ticks: BitConverter.ToInt64(protector.Unprotect(protectedDateTime), 0));
```

Comment: Is Ticks a consistent value among .NET implementations on different platforms? If not, should use ISO date strings instead, unless your system is always protecting/unprotecting something on the same machine/architecture

Comment: Yes it is a public API and contains the number 100-nanosecond intervals elapsed since midnight on January 1st in year 0001 represented as `long` (64 bit signed integer)

Comment: Nice that they took care of that, since various operating systems have been using different "starting" dates internally and it would be a real mess when trying to move that value around if they hadn't

Answer (score 2):

Probably you need to use strings instead

```
string sEnrollmentDate = _protector.Protect(student.EnrollmentDate.ToString())
```

note that the ToString would protect a localized text form of the date, so you'd better use some method that returns an ISO date string instead (see [Given a DateTime object, how do I get an ISO 8601 date in string format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114983/given-a-datetime-object-how-do-i-get-an-iso-8601-date-in-string-format))

Comment: Thank you, could not convert it to string.  Update my question.

Comment: what do you mean when you say couldn't convert it? The idea is that you'd pass a ISO date string to the protector instead of a date and then keep what is returned by the protector into a string (not into a DateTime object). Then when decrypting you'd get back a string and convert it from the ISO date string format to a DateTime object

Comment: Created an answer to explain why this isn't possible without using a different data type to store the protected value.

Comment: Guess you mean a different datatype than DateTime. ISO dates as strings should be fine