# Unable to bind parameter with unsupported type: System.DateTime

Tags: c#, sqlite, datetime, uwp

When reading json data from webapi I got a datetime column value as '2013-07-26T13:47:58.59'. When trying to insert this value to database using sqlite - an error shows

> SQLitePCL.SQLiteException: 'Unable to bind parameter with unsupported
>   type: System.DateTime'

How can I change this datetime format to '2013-07-26 13:47:58.590'?

Comment: Please post the complete code you are using to insert the value.

Comment: It would be better to show a [MCVE] demonstrate your problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Given a DateTime object, how do I get an ISO 8601 date in string format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114983/given-a-datetime-object-how-do-i-get-an-iso-8601-date-in-string-format)

Comment: SQLite doesn't accept a C# DateTime object as a data type. It needs to be a string formated as ISO 8601 as you seem to have already discovered.  And IMO I don't see any reason why this question needs a code example, it's very straight forward.