# Getting Error In Abenity API

Tags: c#, api

I'm using Abenity API example as follows:

```
abenityApi.PostSsoMember(new SsoMemberPayload()
    {
        Address = "1 Main St.",
        City = "Nashville",
        ClientUserId = "1",
        Country = "US",
        Email = "jane.doe@maildomain.com",
        Username = "jane.doe@maildomain.com",
        FirstName = "Jane",
        LastName = "Doe",
        SendWelcomeEmail = true,
        State = "TN",
        Zip = "37201"
    });
```

with correct api keys and I'm always receiving following error:

> {"method":"sso_member","status":"fail","error":{"signature":"Creation
>   Time (crea tion_time) is required"}}

Can you help me ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You do not provide the required `creation_time` key with a valid ISO 8601 date value. Citing from the [Abenity Member API](https://abenity.com/developers/api/members) documentation:

> `creation_time` - String. Required. ISO 8601 date (e.g.
>   **2004-02-12T15:19:21+00:00**). Requests that are greater than 500 seconds
>   different than the API Server's time will result in an error. The API
>   Server's time and your server's time should be coordinated with
>   http://www.time.gov.

As stated, take care your server time is coordinated with a time server.

Comment: Thanks, I'm using C# library for communicating with Abenity REST Api, where the creation_time string is in "DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz")" fromat. What format should I use?

Comment: The sample on GitHub uses the same as you do. Try it like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114983/given-a-datetime-object-how-do-i-get-an-iso-8601-date-in-string-format

Comment: I've used all date formats given as above but still I'm getting same error.

Comment: Is server time coordinated? `Utility.UrlEncode(creationTime)`? Have you tried it with the GitHub sample?

Comment: I'm using github sample https://github.com/Abenity/abenity-csharp, I've also followed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114983/given-a-datetime-object-how-do-i-get-an-iso-8601-date-in-string-format, but still I'm getting creation_time error

Comment: Sorry, despite all the effort, you probably have to file a [support ticket](https://abenity.com/support).