# DateTime formats for Python3 date strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I have the following String representing a date time that I need to read into a valid Python3 datetime object. My best attempt so far:

```
from datetime import datetime

string_date = '2013-04-27T12:27:52.100Z'
in_memory_date = datetime.strptime(created, '???')
```

I'm struggling with the date format for this string (`???`). Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Comment: that way: [strftime-strptime-behavior](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) there a table what %... to put where, simply adjust it to your pattern

Comment: I couldn't find a dup, but you can simply use `'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'`.

Comment: This is the exact oppisite: how to create a ISO 8601 from datetime - in includes the parseformat string needed:[given-a-datetime-object-how-do-i-get-an-iso-8601-date-in-string-format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114983/given-a-datetime-object-how-do-i-get-an-iso-8601-date-in-string-format)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
datetime.datetime.strptime("2013-04-27T12:27:52.100Z", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
```

Comment: I am unsure ... normally answers should contain more then one line of code - thats what comments are for ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) function from pandas. It is simpler.

```
pd.to_datetime(string_date)
Timestamp('2013-04-27 12:27:52.100000')
```