# c# return iso datetime rather than json datetime

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I have two projects with one is a server and the other one is the caller. my server is returning an object from its function, and when the caller receive the result, it is receiving the data as a json.

Class

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int myInt{ get; set; }
    public string myString{ get; set; }
    public DateTime myDate{ get; set; }
}
```

Server Side

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
     var tmpResult = await . . .
     return new MyClass();
}
```

Caller Side

```
HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
webRequest.Method = "POST";
Stream dataStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream();
WebResponse response = webRequest.GetResponse();
dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream))
{
     responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
     reader.Close();
}
```

currently, my response is like :

> {"myInt":0,"myString":"a","myDate":"/Date(1531908040342)/"}

What I want to achieve would be like :

> {"myInt":0,"myString":"a","myDate":"2018-07-18 00:00:00.000"}

I thought that by adding JsonConverter to my class, it would solve my problem.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int myInt{ get; set; }
    public string myString{ get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(CustomDateTimeConverter))]
    public DateTime myDate{ get; set; }
}

class CustomDateTimeConverter : IsoDateTimeConverter
{
    public CustomDateTimeConverter()
    {
        base.DateTimeFormat = "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.fff";
    }
}
```

But, the response that I get was still the same. I wonder how should I change my model to make it happen? or should I convert my response into object, then re-serialize again?

*Addition : I hope that I dont need to type anything like `DateTime.ToString()`. Because this way, I need convert my response to object, then type it 1 by 1. What I hope that I could get, is the response from server, already convert it to ISO format rather than Json Format

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Given a DateTime object, how do I get an ISO 8601 date in string format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114983/given-a-datetime-object-how-do-i-get-an-iso-8601-date-in-string-format)

Comment: @NitinSawant this would be the worst case, so that I need to type my class 1 by 1, and in the `DateTime` field, I change it to `DateTime.ToString()`. I hope I could find a better solution

Comment: try this var date = DateTime.Now;
date.ToString("dd/mm/yyyy h:mm:ss"));

Comment: @D-johnAnshani please try to understand the context of the question. It's about ASP.NET MVC serializing a response object. There's no manual string manipulation there.

Comment: oh yes @CodeCaster

Comment: Which json converter are you using?  The Newtonsoft one should do this out of the box.

Comment: @Neil yes I am using newtonsoft. Still with no luck

Comment: Did you define JSON.Net to be used as serializer, like shown here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14591750/setting-the-default-json-serializer-in-asp-net-mvc ? The default for json serialization is still .NET's own JavaScriptSerializer.

Comment: @derpischer I cant log in to my computer now. i would try it as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert object to JSON using this settings:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat
};

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, settings);
```

https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeDateFormatHandling.htm