# AspNet Core - Specify the DateTime Format

Tags: c#, datetime, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am consuming a third party API which expects an `HTTP header` value as below (using the format below).

**Date: 2017-10-15T14:25:21Z**

When I try to add the header as below, I am getting invalid date time format error (when the client inject the header during runtime)

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Date", "2017-10-15T14:25:21Z");
```

So I change the code above to as below

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Date = DateTime.UtcNow;
```

However, the API throws back an exception "Hmac timestamp 2019-01-02 is not a valid ISO8601 dateTime"

How do I pass the expected date time format in the HTTP request header?

> EDIT

-
I know how to get a date string in a specified format.  What I am asking here is how do I pass a UTC date object to HTTP header as below with a specific format. I also realise that datetime object cant have a format in it.

```
  **client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Date = DateTime.UtcNow**
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Given a DateTime object, how do I get an ISO 8601 date in string format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114983/given-a-datetime-object-how-do-i-get-an-iso-8601-date-in-string-format)

Comment: @Corey, why do you think it is a duplicate? It's not about converting a date into a specified format but more on how to pass the correct format of the date into HTTP request header

Comment: Retracted, since you seem to be having a different issue.

Answer (score 0):

Do that like this

```
DateTime dt=Convert.ToDateTime("2019-01-02");           
string yourdate = dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ");           
Console.WriteLine(yourdate);
```

Working example

[image]