# C# DateTime format that will contain all the data

Tags: c#, datetime

I need to send `DateTime` object as `string`

So that I'll be able to parse this string back to `DateTime` and not lose data.

i.e. restore the original object.

Which format should I use?

Comment: Why can't you "send" it as a datetime object? The answer depends on how you are sending it.

Comment: yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss (with timezone or UTC if need be).

Comment: @DavidG, because the system works in this way...

Comment: @CetinBasoz that's a localized format.

Comment: Yes localized and safe for that reason. As I added, if you want UTC just use UTC.

Comment: @CetinBasoz and *definitely unsafe* for that reason. It will *fail* in any locale that doesn't use that specific format. Nothing says that the four letters at the front are a year, or that the middle ones are months. The ISO8601 format is unambiguous though

Comment: Nothing says? Check ISO 8601 as an example.

Comment: @Cetin that's NOT ISO8601. ISO8601 uses dashes.

Comment: If you say so :)

Comment: @CetinBasoz There is no "if you say so", it's simply a fact. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114983/given-a-datetime-object-how-do-i-get-an-iso-8601-date-in-string-format) for example.

Comment: @CetinBasoz check the actual [ISO standard](https://www.iso.org/iso-8601-date-and-time-format.html). You can check the [ISO 8601 Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) to avoid downloading the actual standard text

Comment: ISO8601 says it is yyyy-MM-dd, not as you claimed it could be yyyy-dd-MM

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, if you don't want to fail with some locale, say on SQL Server, then you shouldn't even use dashes or / or . - any separator for date part. That fails on sone language settings and versions (thus the one you found safe fail).

Comment: @CetinBasoz SQL Server specifically handles ISO8601 format, which uses dashes. It's unclear why you are digging in so much on this.

Comment: @CetinBasoz - noone claimed that *ISO8601* says it could be `yyyy-dd-MM`. What *was* claimed is that with your proposed format `"yyyy/MM/dd"` you could for example get something like `"2019/02/11"` and there would be no way to definitely know that this would really be `"2019-02-11"` or `"2019-11-02"`. *Only* if both sides agree, what format should be used. -- *With* ISO8601 there is *no* ambiguity, because `"yyyy-dd-MM"` is **not** ISO8601.

Comment: @Corak, where would it say ISO8601? You are agreeing upon it, no? PK implied it could be yyyy/dd/MM, wouldn't it be always yyyy/MM/dd too upon agreement. My fault was not saying ISO8601 but just yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss?

Comment: @DavidG, in some older versions of MS SQL, with some language combinations, it is well demonstrated that MS SQL Server fail to interpret yyyy-MM-dd ... aka ISO8601 format. It can only interpret it when you remove the separators. You might find the demo code on MSDN forums if you search.

Comment: @CetinBasoz - using dashes implicitly broadcasts "this is ISO8601". Using slashes *doesn't*. -- Also, `"/"` in the format string will be replaced by the `DateSeparator` of whatever `DateTimeFormat` is being used. That *might* also be `"/"`, but doesn't *have* to be. Try `DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE"))` for example. Dashes in the format string will remain untouched.

Comment: @Corak, so you are saying 01-01-2019 is ISO8601. Good:) The thing doesn't have anything to do with cultures. Try parsing with /, . or -. All parses correctly.

Comment: @CetinBasoz - No I don't. Yes it does. Have fun.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [round-trip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings?view=netframework-4.7.2#Roundtrip) format "O":

```
string s = dateTime.ToString("O");
DateTime d =
    DateTime.ParseExact(s, "O", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind);
```

Comment: Seems Good, I just did not understand the difference between "o" and "O".

Comment: @SeReGa there is no difference between the two.

Comment: While you are right to suggest the round-trip format, my comment on the question still stands. Also, you need to use the same culture when converting to string as well as parsing back to a date.

Comment: @DavidG "O" is always invariant, no need to specify a culture.

Comment: D'oh, yes, of course it does. But I would still strive to not convert it to anything if possible.

Comment: Keep in mind that while the round-trip format does what it's supposed to, `DateTimeKind.Local` could mean different things between the sender and the receiver.  If so, the resulting timestamp will be the same point in time (the UTC equivalent), but will be adjusted to the receiver's local time zone.  If you don't want that behavior, you need to use a `DateTimeOffset` instead of a `DateTime`.