# Why Does Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject Surround Result With Quotes?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

This sample code

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(2020, 01, 27);
string str = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(date, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None,
    new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings() {
         DateFormatHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat });
```

returns str = "\"2020-01-27T00:00:00\"" - so the string's content is surrounded with quotes (here written in escaped form as the debugger does).

But I want only the date and time in ISO format. Why are there quotes? How can I avoid them without removing them afterwards?

I already looked for all serializer options, but didn't found the one helping me...

Comment: Because Json.NET is a JSON serializer but JSON [has no primitive format for dates & times](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DatesInJSON.htm) so serializes a `DateTime` as a JSON string primitive, which is quoted as required by the [JSON standard](https://www.json.org/json-en.html).

Comment: The quotes are to satisfy the [json syntax](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_syntax.asp) for a string, as there is no global datetime object like there is for an integer for example.

Comment: you have to format datetime.  https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/date-and-time-format-in-c-sharp-programming1

Comment: The [dotnetfiddle.com example for NewtonSoft](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Mobile?id=5VR5rs#code-editor) doesn't seem to have this problem..

Comment: Do these comments answer your question, or do you still need some help?  What problem are you trying to solve?  [Given a DateTime object, how do I get an ISO 8601 date in string format?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/114983/3744182)?

Comment: Thank you all - I think I got it now. Json formatting works perfect as long as you create a complete json, but creating only single fields is problematic because this would not satisfy the json rules.

Comment: I wanted to avoid defining the date format as a string - json formatting creates a perfect ISO date. Is there a standard for the DateTime.ToString() function, so I can refer to this ISO format and not needing to write date.ToString("yyyy’-‘MM’-‘dd’T’HH’:’mm’:’ss.fffffff")?

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/115034/3744182) to [Given a DateTime object, how do I get an ISO 8601 date in string format?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/114983/3744182) seems to show what you want, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/AMKLKo.  Or you could just add a const string somewhere: `public class Constants { public const string IsoDateTimeFormat = "yyyy’-‘MM’-‘dd’T’HH’:’mm’:’ss.fffffff"; }`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm now using date.ToString("s") for ISO 8601 format and that's it! Solved all my issues (for this question...)!

Answer (score 1):

If you look up the [Specification](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt) of Json, you would notice that it doesn't contain a proper definition of DateTime.

This is the reason, by default, Json.Net represents DateTime as string using the ISO norms representation. Having said so, one alternative representation would be using `JavaScriptDateTimeConverter`.

This isn't exactly ISO norm, and not even valid JSON according to specification(given in link above), but Json.Net does support it. For example,

```
var  data = new Person{Name= "ABC", Dob= new DateTime(2020, 01, 27)};
string str = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data,new JavaScriptDateTimeConverter());
```

Output

```
{"Name":"ABC","Dob":new Date(1580063400000)}
```

Please note that, you would need to use the `JavaScriptDateTimeConverter` for Deserializing as well.

```
var dt = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(str,new JavaScriptDateTimeConverter());
```