# Setting DateTime property value in a List<>

Tags: c#, datetime, arraylist

I am building a Blazor WebAssembly application with a separate ASP.NET Core Web API project.  I would like to create a new List including the users date of birth and other date times.  I am getting Compiler Error CS0029: cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'System.DateTime'.  If I add quotes, I get an error of 'string' to 'System.DateTime'. What is the correct way to set the DateTime property value in a new list?

Controller

```
public class Controller : ControllerBase
{
    List<Person> people = new List<Person>
    {
        new Person {Id = 1, Name = "John Doe", DOB = YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS},
        new Person {Id = 2, Name = "Jane Doe", DOB = YYYY-MM-DD}
    };
}
```

Model

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You don’t format the date time when you _set_ it, you format it when you _show_ it.

Comment: See also this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114983/given-a-datetime-object-how-do-i-get-an-iso-8601-date-in-string-format?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

You can set the time first, and then format the time, such as this:

[image]

[image]

For more usage, please refer to the official document:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

Comment: I meant input format, not time format.  The only method that does not give an error is DateTime.Now.  DateTime(2021, 8, 6) gives compile error CS1955: Non-invocable member 'name' cannot be used like a method.  How is a date and time value specified in a new list?

Comment: Will DateTime.Parse("2021-08-06") work as intended?  This does not give an error.